# Search and change background color depending on 'text'?

Tags: javascript

I have a case like this:

```
<span class="pos" hclass="pos" htag="span">verb</span>
<span class="pos" hclass="pos" htag="span">adverb</span>
<span class="pos" hclass="pos" htag="span">adjective</span>
```

And I want to change background-color of the 'Text' in class 'pos' depending on the results they find, like this:

```
if 'verb', set background-color: green.
if 'adverb', set background-color: purple.
if 'adjective', set background-color: yellow.
```

How can I do this?

I'm a neophyte on this language, could you guide me please?

Comment: You can use ```switch case```.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ***switch*** statement and then assign a class that will style your element as you'd like using `el.classList.add('classname')`.

```js
//get the element nodeList
const pos = document.querySelectorAll('.pos');

//iterate over the nodeList
pos.forEach(el => {
  //switch statement for the elements textual content
  switch (el.textContent) {
    case 'verb':
      // add the class for verbs
      el.classList.add('verbs');
      break;
    case 'adverb':
      // add the class for adverbs
      el.classList.add('adverbs');
      break;
    case 'adjective':
      // add the class for adjectives
      el.classList.add('adj');
      break;
  }
})
```

```css
.verbs {
  background-color: red;
}

.adverbs {
  background-color: green;
}

.adj {
  background-color: blue;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<span class="pos" hclass="pos" htag="span">verb</span>
<span class="pos" hclass="pos" htag="span">adverb</span>
<span class="pos" hclass="pos" htag="span">adjective</span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was very thoughtful of you. Hope you have a great day, Sir!

Comment: You as well, glad the code helped you out ;) happy coding